# Regex - find data inside left and right encloses

Tags: java, regex

I have this string:

```
text=123+456+789&xxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzz
```

I need to extract `123+456+789`

What I done so far is:

```
String s = "text=123+456+789&xxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzz";
String ps = "text=(.*)&";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

And I got **all** text until the last `&` which is: `123+456+789&xxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyy` while the requested output is: `123+456+789`

Any suggestions how to fix it (regex is mandatory)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negated character class:

```
String ps = "text=([^&]*)";
```

The value you need will be in Group 1.

The `[^&]` matches any character but an ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

You almost getting, you need to make your regex lazy (or non greedy) like this:

```
String ps = "text=(.*?)&";
             here ---^
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW4uO7/1)**

Comment: Lazy dot matching always loses in performance to a negated character class.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the comment. Actually, it's the cleanest way in my opinion but it is slower than having `text=([^&]*)` since my regex has more backtracking

Comment: @stribizhev I agree with you, anyway don't think OP has a monster text where this impact can be noticed.

Comment: I didn't see the beginning of the string.  Facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

> ([0-9+]+)

Link : https://regex101.com/r/xU2zF4/1

java code :

```
String s = "text=123+456+789&xxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzz";
String ps = "([0-9+]+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // value of s
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // returns 123+456+789
}
```